# Delay a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this for a success function:

```
success: function(data){
        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
          data = $.trim(data);
          if(data == 'true'){
            $('#myTab a[href="#intro"]').tab('show');
          }
          else{
            $("#alert").attr('class', 'alert alert-warning');
            $("#alert").html('Your Pass Phrase was incorrect! Please try again.');
          }
      }
```

How do I delay the `$('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');` from happening for 1200 milliseconds.

I've tried:

```
$('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide').delay(1200);
```

But it did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

`setTimeout()` function with parameters function you wanna call and time of delay in milliseconds.

like

```
 var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      //codes here.
  },1200);
```

and

use `clearTimeout(timeout);` to stop the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Please use setTimeout() to delay in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript setTimeout function. Like so..

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide')
},
1200);
```

This will do what you're asking. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide')
},
1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

put you code inside

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
  },1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.delay` before calling `.modal`. See the [example on jQuery API documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).